# Update JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

The .json file I want to update has this structure:

```
{
  "username": "abc",
  "statistics": [
    {
      "followers": 1234,
      "date": "2018-02-06 02:00:00",
      "num_of_posts": 123,
      "following": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want it to insert a new statistic like so

```
{
  "username": "abc",
  "statistics": [
    {
      "followers": 1234,
      "date": "2018-02-06 02:00:00",
      "num_of_posts": 123,
      "following": 123
    },
    {
      "followers": 2345,
      "date": "2018-02-06 02:10:00",
      "num_of_posts": 234,
      "following": 234
    }
  ]
}
```

When working with

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(information, fp, indent=2)
```

the file will always be overwritten. But I want the items in statistics to be added. I tried reading the file in many possible ways and append it afterwards but it never worked.
The data is coming written in the information variable just like

```
information = {
  "username": username,
  "statistics": [
      {
          "date": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
          "num_of_posts": num_of_posts,
          "followers": followers,
          "following": following
      }
  ]
}
```

So how do I update the .json file that my information is added correctly?

Comment: `json.reads`, modify, `json.dump`

Comment: Where is the new data coming from? Please show us your existing code so we can tell you how to fix  it.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry, I updated it. It's simply written into the variable information.

Comment: *tried reading the file in many possible ways and append it afterwards but it never worked.*... Please show **that** code

Comment: It is a file, not a database.  Using a csv file, one could append new rows to the end.  Amending JSON objects, however, requires amending the file in place and adjusting any needed brackets, commas or parenthesis. You are probably better off to read the file as JSON, modify your objects, and then use `json.dump` to overwrite the file with the new objects.

Comment: You may want to bite the bullet and investigate using a NoSQL database such as MongoDB (https://www.mongodb.com/).  The problem with any file based approach is that you must rewrite the entire file after each change.  If the file is large, this becomes increasingly expensive, especially if many small changes are made.  A database solution would be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander ! I think you are right, I am now using a simple csv to store my data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to do something along the lines of:

```
def append_statistics(filepath, num_of_posts, followers, following):

    with open(filepath, 'r') as fp:
        information = json.load(fp)

    information["statistics"].append({
        "date": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        "num_of_posts": num_of_posts,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following
    })

    with open(filepath, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(information, fp, indent=2)
```

Comment: Thanks :) This actually helped me! I was finally able to read the file and modify it. Even though I think the JSON syntax is way too strict for this little project. That's why I'm working with csv now which makes it way easier for me.

Comment: @lucanello Glad it helped. CSV sounds like a good idea for this task, as then you can just append to the end of the file instead of rewriting it every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the `.json` file and then append the new dataset and dump that data. See the code.

```
import json
appending_statistics_data = {}

appending_statistics_data["followers"] =  2346
appending_statistics_data["date"] = "2018-02-06 02:10:00"
appending_statistics_data["num_of_posts"] =  234
appending_statistics_data["following"] = 234

with open(file.json, 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

data['statistics'].append(appending_statistics_data)    
#print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))               


with open(file.json, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function:

```
def append_statistics(filepath, num_of_posts, followers, following):
    new_statistics_record={
        "date": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        "num_of_posts": num_of_posts,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following
    }

    with open(filepath, 'r') as fp:
        information = json.load(fp)

    information["statistics"].append(new_statistics_record)

    with open(filepath, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(information, fp, indent=2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally, you don't directly update the file that you are reading from.

You might consider:

1. read from source file.
2. do processing
3. write to a new temp file
4. close both source file and temp file
5. rename (move) the temp file back to source file

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer.