# Updating JSON when there is multiple objects named the same - Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am new to the JSON python lib.

I have this JSON file:

```
   {
        "usrdata": [
            {
                "user": "---/ LandiPlayz \\---#****",
                "money": 10
            },
            {
                "user": "Snubz#****",
                "money": 10
            }
        ]
    }
```

and I need to modify the "money" field of one of the users. There will be more added users, so I need to find which one it is by finding the users name. Is that possible, or should I do format the file differently.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can, you just need to know the user value. No matter how the JSON values are , if the you have the info to reach the value, you'll be good

Comment: You don't really edit the file; you decode it, modify the resulting in-memory data structure, and write out a new file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update json file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949637/how-to-update-json-file-with-python) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035762/python-read-json-file-and-modify  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634389/update-json-file-in-python

Comment: @azro Thanks for that. What do you mean reach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the user_infos, and when getting the good one, update the `money`

```
json_value =    {
        "usrdata": [
            {"user": "---/ LandiPlayz \\---#****","money": 10},
            {"user": "Snubz#****","money": 10}
        ]
    }
username = "Snubz#****"
new_money = 50

for user_info in json_value["usrdata"]:
    if user_info['user'] == username:
        user_info['money'] = new_money
```